# Adding keys to a dict gives TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, yaml

I'm trying to edit a YAML file with my own variables.

This is my YAML template that I'm editing:

```yaml
Mappings:
  PrivateLink:
    EndPointService:
      EndPointService: hostname1
      PrincipalName: ""
  NLBName:
    NLBName:
      Name: hostname1
  TargetName:
    hostname1-22:
      Name: hostname1-22
      VpcId: vpc-123
      Id: "i-123"
```

My goal is to loop over a list port numbers I have and use them to create new Target Groups.

For example, if my ports list is `[22, 80, 443]`, the output YAML will look like this:

```yaml
Mappings:
  PrivateLink:
    EndPointService:
      EndPointService: hostname1
      PrincipalName: ""
  NLBName:
    NLBName:
      Name: hostname1
  TargetName:
    #Editing is done here
    hostname1-22:
      Name: hostname1-22
      VpcId: vpc-123
      Id: "i-123"
    hostname1-80:
      Name: hostname1-80
      VpcId: vpc-123
      Id: "i-123"
    hostname1-443:
      Name: hostname1-443
      VpcId: vpc-123
      Id: "i-123"
```

So for my function looks like this:

```py
def editEndpointServiceTemplate(endpoint_service_template_path):
    yaml = YAML()
    yaml.indent(mapping=3)
    ports_list = ast.literal_eval(configParser.get("Ports", "Ports"))

    #Load yaml file
    with open(endpoint_service_template_path) as fp:
        data = yaml.load(fp)
    
    for i in range(0, len(ports_list)):
        tg_name = service_name + "-" + str(ports_list[i])
        data['Mappings']['TargetName'][tg_name] = None
        data['Mappings']['TargetName'][tg_name]['Name'] = "test"

    
    #Write new yaml file
    with open(endpoint_service_template_path, 'w') as fp:
        yaml.dump(data, fp)
```

I'm failing on this error:

```
data['Mappings']['TargetName'][tg_name]['Name'] = "test"
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

I guess I can't access a key I just created for some reason but I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Somewhere in `data['Mappings']['TargetName'][tg_name]` is a string. See in your data.

Comment: `tg_name` is a string. I'm guessing that's the issue but why? I'm not trying to change it. I created a new key and now I would like to access it to create more sub-keys and values.

Comment: Then `tg_name` should be a dict. You can not assign keys to a string.

Comment: thanks @lllrnr101 . When I try to change it to `dict(tg_name)` I get a different error so I googled around and found that using `eval(tg_name)` can be used. I tried but still get some error: `File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'dub' is not defined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by changing:

```py
data['Mappings']['TargetName'][tg_name] = None
```

To this:

```py
data['Mappings']['TargetName'][tg_name] = {}
```

Now it's fixed. Guess I had to set it to a dict object.